# Return Multiple specific Items in an array by index

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of diagnoses, all of which have specific indexes as seen below from the console:

```
{M24.2: {…}, M51.2: {…}, S03.5: {…}, J10.1: {…}, J06.9: {…}, …}
F43.2
: 
{code: 'F43.2', name: 'Adjustment disorders', latin: 'Perturbationes adaptationis'}
H35.29
: 
{code: 'H35.29', name: 'Other proliferative retinopathy', latin: 'Alia retinopathia proliferativa'}
H54.7
: 
{code: 'H54.7', name: 'Unspecified visual loss', latin: 'Amblyopia NAS'}
J03.0
: 
{code: 'J03.0', name: 'Streptococcal tonsillitis', latin: 'Tonsillitis (palatina) streptococcica'}
J06.9
: 
{code: 'J06.9', name: 'Acute upper respiratory infection, unspecified', latin: 'Infectio acuta respiratoria superior non specificata'}
J10.1
: 
{code: 'J10.1', name: 'Influenza with other respiratory manifestations, other influenza virus codeentified', latin: 'Influenza cum aliis manifestationibus respiratoriis ab agente virali codeentificato'}
L20
: 
{code: 'L20', name: 'Atopic dermatitis', latin: 'Atopic dermatitis'}
L60.1
: 
{code: 'L60.1', name: 'Onycholysis', latin: 'Onycholysis'}
M24.2
: 
{code: 'M24.2', name: 'Disorder of ligament', latin: 'Morbositas ligamenti'}
M51.2
: 
{code: 'M51.2', name: 'Other specified intervertebral disc displacement', latin: 'Alia dislocatio disci intervertebralis specificata'}
N30.0
: 
{code: 'N30.0', name: 'Acute cystitis', latin: 'Cystitis acuta'}
S03.5
: 
{code: 'S03.5', name: 'Sprain and strain of joints and ligaments of other and unspecified parts of head', latin: 'Distorsio et/sive distensio articulationum et/sive…m partium aliarum sive non specificatarum capitis'}
S62.5
: 
{code: 'S62.5', name: 'Fracture of thumb', latin: 'Fractura [ossis/ossium] pollicis'}
Z57.1
: 
{code: 'Z57.1', name: 'Occupational exposure to radiation'}
Z74.3
: 
{code: 'Z74.3', name: 'Need for continuous supervision'}
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
```

I have an array of codes stored in the variable below:

```
const codes = ['Z57.1', 'Z74.3', 'M51.2']
```

How would I only return the diagnoses that have the indexes listed in the variable "codes"?

Expected result would be:

```
  Z57.1
    {code: 'Z57.1', name: 'Occupational exposure to radiation'}
    Z74.3
    : 
    {code: 'Z74.3', name: 'Need for continuous supervision'}
   M51.2
    : 
    {code: 'M51.2', name: 'Other specified intervertebral disc displacement', latin: 'Alia dislocatio disci intervertebralis specificata'}
```

I have tried

codes.map(d => diagnoses[d]) but this didn't work.

Comment: That's not an array, it's an object. You can use `Object.entries()` to convert it to an array of `[key, value]` elements.

Comment: use `Array.prototype.filter`

Comment: It's not clear with the syntax attached as so, please put the actual syntax not copy from console, or even it has option on right click and copy object etc.,

Answer (score 1):

Your `map()` should work, but it will return an array, not an object. You can use `reduce()` to convert that back to an object using the `code` properties as the keys.

```
result = codes.map(d => diagnoses[d])
        .reduce((a, diagnosis) => (a[diagnosis.code] = diagnosis, a), {});
```

Comment: This line of code breaks the app when refreshing the page with the following error: index.tsx:37 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Comment: That means you didn't set `codes`. Fix that.